# FreePBX No connection to Asterisk

Tags: linux, asterisk, voip, sip, freepbx

I am new to asterisk and freePBX. I set up a server years ago but it was very basic and used for less than a month. I’m now launching a new company and found myself in need of a VOIP system so I’m back to asterisk. I installed asterisk on my debian VPS, then installed free PBX. At first i was having issues with getting the freePBX installer to find my asterisk server. After creating an aserisk user on debian and changing the run user-group in /etc/default/asterisk the installer worked.

After the FreePBX installation, localhost/ was redirecting to localhost/admin/config.php but was only showing a blank screen. After running fwconsole ma installall the page started working. Despite that, connection to asterisk cannot be established.

Running fwconsole start works just fine, but when running fwconsole restart I get get UCP Node Server is not running. When running fwconsole restart again I get Core FastAGI Server is not running & UCP Node Server is not running.

**After checking logs for freepbx I found this:**

`[2020-Nov-23 14:42:32] [freepbx.INFO]: Connection attmempt to AMI failed [] []`

**The UCP error log in asterisk yielded this:**

```
2020-11-23 13:40 +00:00: { [Error: Can’t connect to MySQL server on ‘::1’ (111 “Connection refused”)] code: 2003 }

2020-11-23 13:40 +00:00: There was an error with MySQL Connection
```

**ucp_out.log in asterisk displays this:**

```
2020-11-23 13:40 +00:00: Starting FreePBX…
2020-11-23 13:40 +00:00: { AMPDBUSER: ‘freepbxuser’,
2020-11-23 13:40 +00:00: AMPDBPASS: ‘****’,
2020-11-23 13:40 +00:00: AMPDBHOST: ‘localhost’,
2020-11-23 13:40 +00:00: AMPDBNAME: ‘asterisk’,
2020-11-23 13:40 +00:00: AMPDBENGINE: ‘mysql’,
2020-11-23 13:40 +00:00: datasource: ‘’ }
```

I am using mariadb, is there a way maybe this user or database does not exist?

Thank you for your help!

---

Forgot to mention that when accessing Advanced Setting in FreePBX I get a blank page. [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a similar issue on Debian, try using nodejs 10 -- not older and not newer -- and try with asterisk 15 - 16 - 17 on freePBX 15 (2020). Doing so solved the issue for me; it was probably some weird, bug since everything was configured the same way.